# Get emberjs code coverage into sonarqube

Tags: ember.js, jenkins, sonarqube, testem

iam trying to get the code-coverage from my ember-addon project into sonarqube. The CodeCoverage is created with ember-cli-blanket. The LCOV File, which can be imported by the SonarQube runner is created and filled with coverage data, but sonarrunner (inside of jenkins) is printing the following error:

```
SonarQube Runner 2.3
...
15:53:29.949 INFO  - Analysing [/home/build/.jenkins/workspace/$projectname$/$home_dir$/lcov.dat]
15:53:29.970 WARN  - Could not resolve 206 file paths in [/home/build/.jenkins/...
                     first unresolved path: $projectname$/helpers/concat
```

The Job is Configured to execute the following command in the shell:

```
ember test --test-page='tests/index.html?hidepassed&coverage=true'
```

When i explore the project, the directory structure is as follows:

```
-- $projectname$
 |
 |-- app
   |
   |-- helpers
     |
     | - concat.js
```

The LCOV File, looks like this:

```
SF:$projectname$/helpers/concat.js
DA:1,1
DA:2,1
... 
LF:9
LH:9
end_of_record
```

Well, of course SonarRunner does not find the file on the path reported in the LCOV File.

How can i configure this, so that the path in the lcov file is corret?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So, i posted this question on github and got an answer. The solution is, to use "sed" to manually edit the lcov output. In my case, the command looks as follows:

```
sed -i -- 's/SF:$oldName$\/\(.*\)/SF:$newName$\/$newPath$\/\1.js/' lcov.dat
```